# Two questions regarding double short exact sequences

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves, short-exact-sequences

Two short exact sequences on the same objects is called double short exact sequence. The morphism of double short exact sequences is defined in the same way you'd expect, it is a morphism of the underlying objects that commutes with each of the short exact sequences structures (There are two choices we choose either the first short exact sequence for the both of them or the second one.). I have a couple of potentially hard questions regarding double exact sequences that I've failed to make any meaningful progress on:

1. Assume that we are working on a very nice variety $X$(smooth and projective over a field). Is it possible to deform double exact sequence of vector bundles to one that one of the sequences is split? This means given a double exact sequence of vector bundles, find a double exact sequence of torsion-free sheaves on $X\times \mathbb{A}^1$ that at time $0$ it gives back the original one and at time $1$ gives a double exact sequence that at least one of the exact sequences is split. (You can prove if one is split the other one also splits.)
2. Is it possible to put the double exact sequence of vector bundles on $X$ in a finite resolution with split double exact sequences?

If the answers are negative is there any nice category of double exact sequences that any of this is possible?

As a motivation I'd add that double exact sequences are the generators of $K_1(X)$, so this question tries to understand how far away $K_1^{\oplus}(X)$ is from $K_1(X)$.